# Is !0 and !1 something more than a shorthand for true/false?

Tags: javascript, boolean, shorthand

Reading through some code, I came across the use of `!0` and `!1`. I realize that these are shorter ways of writing `true` and `false`.

```
!0 === true
!1 === false
```

This of course save a few bytes, but is there some other reason to use it?

Is there a name for this way of writing it?

Comment: Yes - "confusing and lacking readability" ;)

Comment: I prefer `!!0` (false) and `!!1` (true) for much more clarity and only a 50% size increase! No. Really, use the keywords ..

Comment: @pst Thanks for that, makes much more sense. `!0` being `true` is really easy to misread.

Comment: If you want to know how affects performance, go to http://jsperf.com/checking-if-true-or-false and run the tests

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most JavaScript **minification tools**, like [UglifyJS](http://marijnhaverbeke.nl/uglifyjs), *generate* that code because it's shorter and semantically equivalent. For example, given:

```
var x = true;
if (x) { 
  alert(x); 
}
```

UglifyJS will generate `var x=!0;x&&alert(x)`.

Usually, you don't need to write code using that style; let the *minifiers* do *their* work :-).

Comment: Thanks! I sensed it was the work of a minifier, just wanted to make sure there wasn't something more to it that I was missing.